# Updating the password in the database

Tags: php, mysqli, passwords

First things first. I know bcrypt is a better alternative and I do have a version of the code that has bcrypt it is just godaddy does not support bcrypt. So I have to stick with this version for now.

So I am trying to have a form that updates/change the password of the user. Of course it is not updating.

The code is divided into parts the form:

```
<?php
            if(empty($_POST) === false) {

                if(empty($_POST['current_password']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['password_again'])){

                    $errors[] = 'All fields are required';

                }else if($bcrypt->verify($_POST['current_password'], $user['password']) === true) {

                    if (trim($_POST['password']) != trim($_POST['password_again'])) {
                        $errors[] = 'Your new passwords do not match';
                    } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) { 
                        $errors[] = 'Your password must be at least 6 characters';
                    } else if (strlen($_POST['password']) >18){
                        $errors[] = 'Your password cannot be more than 18 characters long';
                    } 

                } else {
                    $errors[] = 'Your current password is incorrect';
                }
            }

            if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty ($_GET['success']) === true ) {
                echo '<p>Your password has been changed!</p>';
            } else {?>
            <h1>Change Password</h1>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>Log In</legend>
                <?php
                if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
                    $users->change_password($user['id'], $_POST['password']);
                    header('Location: change-password.php?success');
                } else if (empty ($errors) === false) {

                    echo '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>';  

                }
                ?>
                <form action="" method="post">
                   <table border="0">
                   <tr>
                   <td width="200">
                   Current password:
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <input type="password" name="current_password">
                   </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td>
                   New password:
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <input type="password" name="password">
                   </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                   <td>
                   New password again:
                   </td>
                   <td>
                   <input type="password" name="password_again">
                   </tr>
                   </table>
                   <br>
                   <input type="submit" value="Change password">

                </form>
            <?php 
            }
            ?> 
            </fieldset>
```

and the php code:

```
public function change_password($user_id, $password) {

        //global $bcrypt;

        /* Two create a Hash you do */
        $timeNew        = time();
        $email_codeNew = hash("sha256", $username + microtime());
        $password_hash = hash("sha256", $password);

        $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `password` = ?, `email_code` = ?, `time` = ? WHERE `id` = ?");

        $query->bindValue(1, $password_hash);
        $query->bindValue(2, $email_codeNew);
        $query->bindValue(3, $timeNew);
        $query->bindValue(4, $user_id);             

        try{
            $query->execute();
            return true;
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: What happens instead? Is there browser output? Have you checked to make sure everything you think exists does exist?

Comment: You've determined that the intended row in the database isn't updating, but what *does* the code do?  Is there an error message?  Anything in your logs?  When you debug it, at what point does it fail?  What are the relevant runtime values when that happens?

Comment: The Browser output is blank instead of errors or success. It shows blank.

Comment: are there any errors in your PHP error log?

Comment: Is the PHP version really older than 5.3? Otherwise your server will support BCrypt, either with the [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat/blob/master/lib/password.php) from version 5.3.7 upwards, or with the `crypt()` function from 5.3 ([example code](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt)).

Comment: fixed!!! there was a problem with the placement of the function change password in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I have mocked up a php page which does this - it also has been tested and works and i would imagine it might be because of the way you have used === alot in your functions and i am not sure the returns of these functions as they are not here but hopefully if you run the below code you can add and adjust the code you have into it

**EDIT** For testing the current password is always just *password* and the change password function will always pass.

```
<?php

/**
 * @author - Sephedo
 * @for - patgarci @ Stackoverflow
 * @question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728434/updating-the-password-in-the-database
 */

function verifyPassword( $password )
{
    return ( $password == 'password' )? true : false;
}

function changePassword( $password )
{
    return true;
}

if(! empty( $_POST ) )
{
    // check if all of the fields exists and are not empty
    if( empty( $_POST['current_password'] ) or empty( $_POST['password_new'] ) or empty( $_POST['password_again'] ) )
    {
        $errors[] = "All fields are required";
    }
    elseif( verifyPassword( $_POST['current_password'] ) ) // check if the password is valid.
    {
        $_POST['password_new'] = trim( $_POST['password_new'] );
        $_POST['password_again'] = trim( $_POST['password_again'] );

        // check for matching password
        if( $_POST['password_new'] != $_POST['password_again'] ) $errors[] = "Your passwords do not match";

        // check for min limit
        if( strlen( $_POST['password_new'] ) < 6 ) $errors[] = "Your new password needs to be at least 6 characters";

        // check for min limit
        if( strlen( $_POST['password_new'] ) > 18 ) $errors[] = "Your new password needs to be at less than 18 characters";

        // Make sure no errors have occured and change password returns true
        if(! isset( $errors ) and ! changePassword( $_POST['password_new'] ) )
        {
            $errors[] = "An unknown error has occured, please try again";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $errors[] = "Your current password is invalid";
    }

    // DISPLAY ERRORS
    if(! isset( $errors ) )
    {
        echo "<span>Your password has been changed!</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        foreach( (array) $errors as $error )
        {
            echo "<span>$error</span><br />";
        }
    }   
}

?>

<form method="POST" >
<fieldset>
<legend>Change Password</legend>
<label for="current_password">Current Password</label> <input type="password" name="current_password" />
<label for="password_new">New Password</label> <input type="password" name="password_new" />
<label for="password_again">Current Password</label> <input type="password" name="password_again" />
<input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```